# Retrieving object from chrome.storage.local and using it to change CSS of current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension

I am new to developing chrome extensions and I can't tell if this is a promise chain oriented problem (if it's even called that) or am I parsing this object incorrectly.

I am taking a variable from here in popup.js:

```
window.onload=function(){grabData()}

function grabData() {
    let color = document.getElementById('test')
    chrome.storage.local.set({
            'color': color.style.backgroundColor
        }, function () {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript({
            file: "myscript.js"
        });
    });
}
```

And I am sending it over to my content script (myscript.js), which looks like this:

```
chrome.storage.local.get('color',function(block){
    var color = JSON.stringify(block.color)
    $('code').css('background-color', color)
    console.log(color)
});
```

The output of that console.log(color) is `"rgb(107, 91, 149)"`.  Obviously, if I hard-code that color into the `$('code').css()`, it works fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: 'code' ???. If id use `#` and if class use  `.`

Comment: 'code' is a DOM element on stack overflow and it works just fine when hard-coded, so I don't believe that is the issue.  But I did just figure something out.. I think :D

Comment: Is code is dynamic element which append latter ?

Comment: Maybe... but its odd because I can highlight `'code'`, along with all the other class labeled `<span>`'s (`.pln`, `.str`, `.kwd`) within the code block on SO.  So, it shouldn't be a problem at all.  It has to do with the color value that I am inputting. and maybe the timing on when I am actually getting said value?  I am not for sure.  Basically, if you keep my code as is and you input `'red'` instead of the variable `color`, all the correct `<span>` will be highlighted as intended.

Comment: 1) Remove `JSON.stringify` line, 2) your popup script saves the data just once - when the popup is shown but maybe you'd prefer to do it in a click listener, 3) these kind of issues can be solved usually in a matter of a few seconds if you start using devtools debugger properly: set a breakpoint in your content script and when it triggers you can step through the code, inspect the variables and DOM tree and see what happens, 4) note, the popup has its own devtools: right-click the popup, click "inspect".

Answer (score 0):

The API for chrome's storage is asynchronous, so all I needed to do was handle it with either a promise or a callback function.  I chose the callback function option like so:

```
function getColor(key, callback) {
    if (key !== null) {
        chrome.storage.local.get(key,function (obj){
            callback(obj)
        });
    }
}


getColor('color', function(color){
    console.log(color)
})
```

Simple and clean!